# Information about an old frame

Tags: frames

I'm looking for information about this frame- it's my trusty touring bike, and I've been gradually upgrading it - next up is to convert to 700c and a modern chainset (probably sora to keep costs down)

The frame is a Falcon, and has a decal saying 'falcon' on it, but I can't find any information about falcons anywhere - no mention on Sheldon Brown of a falcon model, and scant information on Google.

The frame is steel - 25 inch, lugged. It is pretty much the only original part of the bike!  It was originally a 10speed, down tube shifters, rear indexed, front friction.

So my questions:

Can anyone give me an approximate date for the frame?

Can anyone point me in the direction of a resource about falcons?

Are they a well known brand?

I'm thinking of getting the frame resprayed - is there anything I should bear in mind?

[image: Rear View].

[image: FrontView].

[image: Falcon Decal]

[image: headtube closeup]

[image: Falcon decal]

[image: Dropouts]

Comment: Pictures with more details of the frame would have been helpful, e.g. the "falcon" decal you mentioned or any other decals/stickers etc. that seem relevant.

Comment: Put in closups of the decals & the headtube (you can see the lugging in the forks there) - apologies for the gear in the way of some of them.  (The bike's so covered in mud at the moment that you can barely see them, so these are the clearest pictures I could find!)

Comment: The rear would not have been indexed with downtube shifters.

Comment: The cutaways on the lugs are pretty extreme, suggesting this was originally sold as a lightweight bike -- not inexpensive.

Comment: Some shots of the dropouts would be helpful.

Comment: Shot of the dropouts attached.

Comment: The rear dropout is a very nice one, probably forged, so again a good quality bike.  Only one lug, though it looks to be positioned more for rack than fenders, which is unusual.  Can't make out the front dropout.

Comment: The "indexed" downtube shifters might actually be ratchet which would suggest that it was from sometime in the mid-70s or later. But not much later or the rear would be six-speed.

Answer (score 2):

Falcon Cycles is a British Cycle manufacturer that is still going to this day, although under different ownership

See [Falcon Cycles on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_Cycles)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but have a look at the Falcon Reynolds 531.

Comment: Ahh, yes, it looks similar to some of the models I found of that - except the lugging on the forks.  That said, I found a picture of a falcon professional with the same forks, but more ornate lugging on the headtube!

http://forum.ctc.org.uk/download/file.php?id=5811&sid=6d5d3c9a86030a896322865ef5432ae6&mode=view